# Weird run time error in page directive

Tags: c#, asp.net, runtime

Here is the page directive:

```
<%@ Page Title="Edit Condition" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ManageCondition.aspx.cs" Inherits="Backyard_Cures.ManageCondition" %>
```

That line is throwing this runtime error:

```
 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox'
```

aspx file:

```
<%@ Page Title="Edit Condition" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ManageCondition.aspx.cs" Inherits="Backyard_Cures.ManageCondition" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    <link href="Styles/ManageCondition.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <div class="condition_block">
        <div class="input">
            <div class="label">Title</div>
            <asp:TextBox Text="" CssClass="textbox" ID="Title" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <div class="help">Text</div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="condition_block">
        <div class="input">
            <div class="label">Description</div>
            <asp:TextBox Text="" CssClass="textbox" ID="Description" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <div class="help">Text</div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="condition_block">
        <div class="input">
            <div class="label">Condition Tags</div>
            <asp:TextBox Text="" CssClass="textbox" ID="Tags" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <div class="help">Text</div>
    </div>
    <br />         
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
</asp:Content>
```

code behind file:

```
namespace Backyard_Cures
{
    public partial class ManageCondition : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Condition new_condition = new Condition();
            new_condition.Title = Title.Text;
            new_condition.Content = Description.Text;
            int new_conditionID = Backyard_Cures.AccessLayer.InsertCondition(new_condition);
            Response.Redirect("~/ViewCondition.aspx?ConditionID=" + new_conditionID, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Masterfile code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    public partial class SiteMaster : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: TextBox does not equal TextBox.Text... And what I mean by that is you can't convert a string to a TextBox as a TextBox is a complex object, You can assign it to the TextBox.Text (or might be TextBox.Value on web end *I normally work with forms)

Comment: Yes I understand that. However the error is coming from the page directive?? I didn't assign text to a textbox...

Comment: show your code. I bet in your code behind you did. `System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox txtBox = "string"` when you should do `System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox txtBox.Text = "string"`

Comment: Let me know if still unclear after edits and EWhite's comment as well.

Comment: It's odd to me that this would compile though. Did you mean runtime error or build error? The compiler should have picked up on this invalid cast.

Comment: It is a run time error. I edited it to show my code.

Comment: Like I said at the beginning. The error is getting thrown at the page directive...

Comment: The error is probably in the site master then- I don't see any conversion error in above code. Can you post the code behind for the site master too? Or maybe- can you explain more on how this error is thrown- like is default page ok, and then you click a button and this throws? etc And, maybe it's in the condition object? It's hard to say 'where' it could be without having the project... Is the Condition.Content property a string or a TextBox? (same for .Title)

Comment: What is this trying to accomplish `new_condition.Title = Title.Text` maybe `new_condition.Title = Page.Title`?

Comment: I posted the code behind for the master. However, I can view other pages in the application. So the error is not in the master...

Comment: I am using Linq to SQL. InsertCondition() is a method that inserts the condition object into the condition database.

Answer (score 0):

The page has a property named Title and your textbox id is Title.
You need to change the ID of your textbox

Comment: If this is answer makes more sense why it is a run-time error rather than compile error. I would check into this- probably correct.

Comment: Yeah, I was hopeful too but this does not seem to be solving the issue.

Comment: it does not give a compiler error because the compiler not sure if you intentionally wanted to override the property Page.Title. it should give a warning about that. did you rename the TextBox Id to something other than Title and build you project?

Comment: yeah,I did that. I just came across more issues. I think this has something to do with my namespace. I don't know. I renamed the project/solution a little while back and now it isn't finding my new webforms. I think I will just create a new project. THanks though.